# I'm working on sqlite and cannot figure out the error in the string

Tags: android, sqlite

```
String index=" CREATE INDEX "+index_name+" on "+table_name+" ";
```

Error occurs near `index_name`. I have tried inserting an additional `";"`  to indicate statement end but it didn't work.

ERROR:  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "index_d": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE INDEX result_vinu1 on index_d

Comment: What is your error? Have value inside the `index_name`?

Comment: you need to specify column that you want index that, after table_name you must tell which column you want. sample : http://www.askingbox.com/info/sqlite-creating-an-index-on-one-or-more-columns

Comment: Thanks i specified the column name and it worked...:D

Answer (score 1):

In index, there should be column.

String index=" CREATE INDEX "+index_name+" on "+table_name+" (col_name) ";